# Error while posting data : java.lang.RuntimeException: Export restriction: SunJSSE only :: in jboss server

Tags: java, security, jboss7.x, jsse

While i try to execute some of my code in JBoss server,
i am getting exception like.

```
 Error while posting data : java.lang.RuntimeException: Export restriction: SunJSSE only
```

I tried to run the same in Tomcat and found that its working perfectly.
I have all my jars in the class path

```
jsse.jar
jnet.jar
jcert.jar and
cryptix32.jar
```

I don't understand why JBoss is throwing error.

Comment: Try to add the piece of code that is causing the issue too.

Comment: You don't need `jsse.jar` in the classpath. It's part of the JDK. Possibly you have deployed some ancient version of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should install "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7"

you can get it at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html

That adds support for Unlimited Strength key support to your JDK.